# How can i string value bind in ng-repeat in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

here is my code,

```
 $scope.records = "test,Test1,Test2,test3,test4";
```

i want to bind this value in li tag with ng-repeat.need ouput like as

```
 .test
.Test1
.Test2
.Test3
.Test4
```

Answer (score 2):

Use custom filter.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

var app= angular.module('myApp')
app.controller('MyController', MyController);
  app.filter('split', function() {
    return function(input, spliceplace) {
      var spliceplace = spliceplace || ',';

      return input.split(spliceplace);
    } 
  });

function MyController($scope) {

  $scope.records = "test,Test1,Test2,test3,test4";

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="record in records | split">
  <!-- OR <li ng-repeat="record in records | split:','">-->
      {{record}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice way of using angularJS features

Comment: Welcome @GangadharJannu

Answer (score 0):

You can use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) operator to split the string on `,` then you can use ng-repeat

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', MyController);

function MyController($scope) {

  $scope.records = "test,Test1,Test2,test3,test4";
  $scope.records = $scope.records.split(',');

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="record in records">
      {{record}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check working plnkr for your requirment http://plnkr.co/edit/cmY8S1nKYDBCa1GvmFh6?p=preview

```
<ui>
     <li ng-repeat="record in records" ng-bind="record"></li>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ng-bind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = ["test", "Test1", "Test2", "test3", "test4"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <li ng-repeat="rec in records" ng-bind="rec">
    </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find your Ans:

```
<body>
  <div ng-app="App" ng-controller="mycontroller">
    {{records}} <br/>
    {{arrays}}<br />
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="array in arrays"> {{array}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var app = angular.module("App",[]);
  app.controller("mycontroller",function($scope){
      $scope.records = "test,Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4";
      $scope. arrays = $scope.records.split(',');
  })

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

first convert that string into array and then use ng-repeat in li

Please check the link...

```
[Please check the link]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/manojbagale/jm0kvcmt/1/